# Google cloud-vision-api product search response limits not specified

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision, google-product-search

I've been using Google cloud product search api for 6 months now and the maximum products I could get in a response was 10(which I think is default).

But I want to scale up my system, thus want more products in the productSearch API response. I tried finding out the limits and way to change the returned number of products, couldn't find any in the official documentation (https://cloud.google.com/vision/product-search/docs/searching#product-search-get-similar-products-go).

It would be great if I could get some help here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can check the [Quotas and Limits of Cloud Vision API Product Search](https://cloud.google.com/vision/product-search/quotas) on the documentation.

In case you want to [increase the quotas](https://cloud.google.com/vision/product-search/quotas#quota_increases), and based on the documentation, you should select **"EDIT QUOTAS"** from the [Quotas Page](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?_ga=2.46584999.-1010912299.1562941779&_gac=1.247073072.1563873165.EAIaIQobChMIgtWb59jK4wIVTPlRCh2hywU9EAAYASAAEgIp9_D_BwE). Once you do the request, it will be reviewed and you will be notified either has been approved or denied.

About the limit you are interested in, I found this GitHub repository where you can find the vision-api.json with the specified parameters:

```
"parameters": {
                    "pageSize": {
                      "description": "The maximum number of items to return. Default 10, maximum 100.",
```

Hope this was what you were looking for!

Comment: Hey @eespinola I checked this. There's no where mention of limits on number of products returned in response.

Comment: Sorry, it was my bad. I found this [GitHub link](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-go-client/blob/master/vision/v1/vision-api.json) where you can find some Default limits. I found the limit you where interested about and it is 10 by default. I proceed to edit my last response to update it with the new information.

Comment: Hi @esspinola I read the limits mentioned on Github link, there's no limits mentioned on "productSearch" api. I can see it on product list, create, get apis but not for "ProductSearchResults". ( https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-go-client/blob/4c197b2a726769bfd12605f577c8c05ad81f8021/vision/v1/vision-api.json#L1155 )

Answer (score 1):

[ProductSearchParams](https://cloud.google.com/vision/product-search/docs/reference/rest/v1/ImageContext#ProductSearchParams) is where you would specify parameters when doing a search in ProductSearch. There is no way for you to control how many results are returned when searching.

The ProductSearch api provides you with the N best matches, so even as you scale up to an extremely large product set, it will still return the top results.

Comment: Hi, @Brendan I'm not looking for control over searches, but control over how many of top N results are returned. Currently only top 10 results are returned even if there are more.

Comment: Even on the ProductSearchParams there is no provision to increase the number of results from 10 (if any).

Comment: Right, I was just saying that ProductSearchParams is where you would look for such a setting. They don't expose that setting though. What do you mean by there are more matches? You have different products that could also match?

Comment: Hey @Brendan They do provide expose that setting but not from any of the SDKs. By more matches I mean, if there are more than 10 matching products while productSearch.

Comment: The sample of exposing that setting is https://cloud.google.com/vision/product-search/docs/searching#product-search-get-similar-products-cli

Comment: According to the documentation link you've shared, that only seems to be feasible when using the command-line where you can specify `maxResults`. You can file a feature request in the public issue tracker https://issuetracker.google.com so it gets added in the SDKs.

Comment: Okay, Thanks. :)